Finding the solution to a multi-variable math question using all positive integers from 1 to 9.
Hello I was hoping for some help in solving this riddle. Despite working on it for a couple of days I have been unable to find a solution.
$(a-b)^c$-d=e
fg - hi=3
Where (a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i)= {1,2 3,4,5,6,7,8,9}.
I feel like there is an obvious solution I am missing but I can't find it. Any and all help would be greatly appreciated.

As the value of $d+e \leq 17$, try looking into the possible values of $c$ and $a-b$. Then you can make cases and brute force it for all possible values of $f,g,h,i$

Here is solution using brute force with Mathematica/Wolfram Language
